# Getting Unsafe URL error when trying to send POST request from Firefox console

Tags: node.js, rest, http-post, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

When I try to send a POST request, I am getting Unsafe URL error. How can I solve this problem? What could be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. This is the value the server sets for the [`Referrer-Policy` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy).

You can change it via [`response.setHeader('Referrer-Policy', 'same-origin')`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#responsesetheadername-value) to e.g. `same-origin` or remove it via [`response.removeHeader('Referrer-Policy')`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#responseremoveheadername).